# How to make BLE scan and MQTT publish work in background Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want make some project where Android can scan nearby Beacon/BLE and send it using MQTT. But I want the service to work in the background if the service work in the foreground it will interrupt the scanning process when screen is off.

This is my code for scanning:

```
package com.example.mqtt_active;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button turnon, changeLayout;
    MqttAndroidClient client;
    private boolean state=false;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    public static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 11;
    public static String mqtt_server,mqtt_port,mqtt_id;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("Logger", "On Create Android");

        turnon = findViewById(R.id.turnon);
        changeLayout = findViewById(R.id.mqttSet);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        textView.setText("id "+mqtt_id+" port "+mqtt_port+" server "+mqtt_server);
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://"+mqtt_server+":"+mqtt_port,mqtt_id);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stateCheck();
                Log.d("Logger", "State Check");
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
//        final Handler handlerStop = new Handler();
//        handlerStop.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
//                Log.d("Logger", "Cancel Dsicovery");
//                handlerStop.postDelayed(this, 2000);
//            }
//        }, 2000);

        turnon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!state){
                    turnon.setText("Turn Off");
                    Log.d("Logger", "Turn On State");
//                    if (bluetoothAdapter!=null & bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
//                        if(checkCoarsePermission()){
//                            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
//                        }
//                    }
                    if(mqtt_server!=null||mqtt_id!=null||mqtt_port!=null){
                    try {
                        Log.d("Logger", "Try ");
                        IMqttToken token = client.connect();
                        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                                Log.d("Logger", "Connect MQTT");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connected!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                                Log.d("Logger", "Connect Failed");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connection failed!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Logger", "error"+e);
                    }}
                    state = true;
                }else{
                    turnon.setText("Turn On");
                    state = false;
//                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            }
        });

        changeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MqttActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void stateCheck(){
    if (state){
        if (bluetoothAdapter!=null & bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if(checkCoarsePermission()){
                Log.d("Logger", "Discover");
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        }
    }
//    else {
//        Log.d("Logger", "Cancel");
//        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
//    }
    }

    private boolean checkCoarsePermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver devicesFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action= intent.getAction();

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                int  rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                String RSSI = String.valueOf(rssi);
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"rssi "+RSSI+" "+device.getAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Logger", "Recive data "+device.getAddress());
                if(mqtt_server!=null||mqtt_id!=null||mqtt_port!=null){
                try {
                    Log.d("Logger", "Sending data");
                    String payload = "rssi:"+RSSI+"mac:"+device.getAddress();
                    client.publish("test",payload.getBytes(),0,false);
                } catch ( MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Logger", "Error Sending "+e);
                }}

            }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
            }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"ALLOWED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Forbidden",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } break;
        }
    }
}
```

App Flow:

1. Insert MQTT server, port, id, topic.
2. Turn on the proccess.
3. Android scan BLE/Beacon
4. Android sending MAC/RSSI to MQTT

I hope someone can help to guide me, on how to make the application run in the background?

I'm a beginner, and I don't understand how to implement background service in my application. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a foreground service that will handle your ble scanning and MQTT logic.

See this [article](https://blog.classycode.com/ble-nrf52-remote-control-android-receiver-service-7c72694297fd) with an overview of how to do it. Depending on your build/target SDK, the implementation will vary.